# Express sum of complex exponentials in terms of length and argument

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

I need to write the following expression $$H(\omega)=e^{-i \omega} + e^{-3i \omega}$$
in the form $$r(\omega)e^{i\phi(\omega)}$$
where $$r(\omega), \phi(\omega)\space$$ are real fuctions of omega. So, determine $$|H(\omega)|\space and \space arg(H(\omega)).$$
How should I look at this problem? I can't seem to work out how to get one length and argument from a sum of complex exponentials. (that is, if I computed H(w) correctly.)

Comment: Brute force to start with. Write both terms using $\sin$ and $\cos$, add real and imaginary parts. find length and argument of the result. If you're lucky some trig identities will simplify things. If not, you still have the formulas you need.

Comment: $\omega$ you are taking real or complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming $\text{z}_\text{n}\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $\text{n}$:

$$\text{z}_1+\text{z}_2=\left|\text{z}_1\right|\cdot\exp\left(\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_1\right)+2\pi\cdot\text{k}_1\right)\cdot i\right)+\left|\text{z}_2\right|\cdot\exp\left(\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_2\right)+2\pi\cdot\text{k}_2\right)\cdot i\right)\tag1$$

Where $\text{k}_\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$, 
 $\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\right)\right)+\Im^2\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\right)\right)}$ and $0\le\arg\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\right)<2\pi$.

Using Euler's formula:

$$e^{\varphi i}=\cos\left(\varphi\right)+\sin\left(\varphi\right)\cdot i\tag2$$

So:

- $$\Re\left(\text{z}_1+\text{z}_2\right)=\left|\text{z}_1\right|\cdot\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_1\right)\right)+\left|\text{z}_2\right|\cdot\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_2\right)\right)\tag3$$
- $$\Im\left(\text{z}_1+\text{z}_2\right)=\left|\text{z}_1\right|\cdot\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_1\right)\right)+\left|\text{z}_2\right|\cdot\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}_2\right)\right)\tag4$$

Answer (score 3):

Jan Eerland's answer works in the most general case, but here's a neat "trick" I like to use

$$ e^{-i\omega} + e^{-3i\omega} = e^{-2i\omega} (e^{-i\omega}+e^{i\omega}) = 2\cos(\omega)e^{-2i\omega} $$

Thus $r = 2\cos (\omega)$ and $\phi = -2\omega$

This works for any expression of the form
$$ e^{ai\omega} + e^{bi\omega} = 2\cos\left({a-b\over2}\omega\right)e^{{a+b\over2}i\omega} $$

$$ e^{ai\omega} - e^{bi\omega} = 2i\sin\left({a-b\over2}\omega\right)e^{{a+b\over2}i\omega} $$

Comment: Your expression involving sin is missing a factor of $i$

Comment: @JonathanRayner Fixed. Thanks!